# iOS8--After changing Orientation Keyboard Disappeared

Tags: keyboard, viewdeck

I'm running iOS8, iPhone-6 simulator, Xcode-6.0.1, ViewDeck version-2.2.11.
I have a textField on "RightViewController", It works great in portrait mode,
but as I change the orientation to Landscape and go back to portrait mode after 
clicking in textfield the Keyboard is disappeared and also its layout is disturbed.

This problem is also explained in more detail on GitHub,
https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck/issues/483

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you try to build old project in new xCode6.
So the problem can be in the incorrect migration of old projects to new xCode.

Check if you have `Launch screen interface file base name` key in `Info.plist` file.

If it is the case please find the full answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26899332/2066428).